# Proof concerning eigen values

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

Could somebody help me into proving this theorem?

if $A$ and $B^{H}$ are in $C^{m\times n}$ with $m\geq n$, then $\lambda (AB) = \lambda(BA) \cup \lbrace 0, \ldots ,0\rbrace.$

Thenks,
Elnaz

Comment: Maybe you can add another tag (or more) to your question? So it will be easier to know what subject this theorem is?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $AB x = ax\implies BA(Bx) = aBx$

$BA y = ay\implies AB(Ay) = aAy$

Comment: I'm trying to prove it like this: $A = U_A \sum_A V^{T}_A$ and $B = U_B \sum_B V^{T}_B$

Comment: I'm trying to prove it like this: $A = U_A \sum_A V^{T}_A$ and $B = U_B \sum_B V^{T}_B$ where $U_A \in C^{m\times m}, \sum_A \in C^{m\times n}, V \in C^{n\times n}$ then $AB = U_A \sum_A V^{T}_A U_B \sum_B V^{T}_B$ but I can't group $\sum_A$ and $\sum_B$ together since they are rectangular?

Comment: I'm not following your line of reasoning, how does this help me into proving the above? Could you explain more please?